# How to access album of photos for each row in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have a `UITableView` with few rows. When I hold on a cell the Camera pop-up and I can take photos and to store them in an album of photos.
Each row can have an album of photos. The problem is that when I click on an album, then every time will open me the album with the last picture made and I don't know how to fix this issue with the `indexPath`.
Here is my code:

```
class CustomImg: UIImageView {
    var indexPath: IndexPath?
}


class ChecklistVC: UIViewController {

    lazy var itemSections: [ChecklistItemSection] = {
        return ChecklistItemSection.checklistItemSections()
    }()
    var lastIndexPath: IndexPath!
    var currentIndexPath: IndexPath! 

    ...
    ...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.checklistCell, for: indexPath) as! ChecklistCell

        let itemCategory = itemSections[indexPath.section]
        let item = itemCategory.checklistItems[indexPath.row]


        if item.imagesPath!.isEmpty{
            cell.defectImageHeightConstraint.constant = 0
        }
        else{
            let thumbnailImage = loadImageFromDiskWith(fileName: item.imagesPath?.last ?? String())
            cell.defectImageView.indexPath = indexPath
            cell.defectImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapOnDefectImageView(_:))))
            cell.defectImageHeightConstraint.constant = 100
            cell.defectImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.defectImageView.image = thumbnailImage

            print("For section \(indexPath.section + 1) - row \(String(describing: indexPath.row + 1)) the album photos are: \(String(describing: item.imagesPath))")
        }
        return cell


    }

    @objc func tapOnDefectImageView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){

        guard let img = sender.view as? CustomImg, let indexPath = img.indexPath else { return }

        currentIndexPath = indexPath

        let listImagesDefectVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListImagesDefectID") as! ListImagesDefectVC
        let item = itemSections[indexPath.section].checklistItems[indexPath.row]

        listImagesDefectVC.listImagesPath = item.imagesPath
        listImagesDefectVC.isPhotoAccessedFromChecklist = true
        listImagesDefectVC.delegate = self
        navigationController?.pushViewController(listImagesDefectVC, animated: true)
    }


    // A menu from where the user can choose to take pictures for "Vehicle Damage/Defects" or "Trailer Damage/Defects"
    func showOptionsForAddPhoto(_ indexPath: IndexPath){

        let addPhotoForVehicle = UIAlertAction(title: "Add photo for Vehicle", style: .default) { action in
            self.lastIndexPath = indexPath // Get the position of the cell where to add the vehicle photo
            self.showCamera(imagePicker: self.imagePicker)
        }
        let addPhotoForTrailer = UIAlertAction(title: "Add photo for Trailer", style: .default) { action in
            self.lastIndexPath = indexPath
            self.showCamera(imagePicker: self.imagePicker)
        }
        let actionSheet = configureActionSheet()
        actionSheet.addAction(addPhotoForVehicle)
        actionSheet.addAction(addPhotoForTrailer)
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    // Get the list of the images from ListImagesDefectVC
    extension ChecklistVC: ListImagesDefectDelegate {

        func receiveListImagesUpdated(imagesFromList: [String]?) {

            print("Received Array: \(imagesFromList ?? [])")

            let item = itemSections[currentIndexPath.section].checklistItems[currentIndexPath.row]
            item.imagesPath = imagesFromList
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a GIF with my actual issue. In this capture I click only on Photo 1 and Photo 3. And every time Photo 2 take the value of what I clicked before:

http://g.recordit.co/VMeGZbf7TF.gif

Thank you if you are reading this.

Comment: You are the one saying `item.imagesPath?.last`. So now you are complaining that you are being shown the last image?

Comment: That one is for thumbnail. For each row which have an album I want to show as Thumbnail the last image from the album if the album have any photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in `tapOnDefectImageView` you should use the clicked indexPath for the cell not `lastIndexPath` which is the reason why clicking a row shows photos of last clicked indexPath

so either add this gesture inside the cell and in the action method do

```
delegate?.tapOnDefectImageView(self) //// self = cell
```

and use

```
@objc func tapOnDefectImageView(_ gest:ChecklistCell){
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(cell) else { return }
    let listImagesDefectVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListImagesDefectID") as! ListImagesDefectVC
    let item = itemSections[indexPath.section].checklistItems[indexPath.row]

    listImagesDefectVC.listImagesPath = item.imagesPath
    listImagesDefectVC.isPhotoAccessedFromChecklist = true
    listImagesDefectVC.delegate = self
    navigationController?.pushViewController(listImagesDefectVC, animated: true)
}
```

**or create**

```
 class CustomImg:UIImageView { 
   var indexPath:IndexPath? 
 }
```

with this inside `cellForRowAt`

```
  cell.defectImageView.indexPath = indexPath 
  cell.defectImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapOnDefectImageView)))
```

then assign the class to the imageView of the cell and now you can do

```
@objc func tapOnDefectImageView(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    guard let img = sender.view as? CustomImg ,  let indexPath = img.indexPath  else { return }
    let listImagesDefectVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListImagesDefectID") as! ListImagesDefectVC
    let item = itemSections[indexPath.section].checklistItems[indexPath.row]

    listImagesDefectVC.listImagesPath = item.imagesPath
    listImagesDefectVC.isPhotoAccessedFromChecklist = true
    listImagesDefectVC.delegate = self
    navigationController?.pushViewController(listImagesDefectVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I implemented but is not opening the album now. Looks like is executing the return from guard every time.

Comment: Is not possible to keep the LongPress gesture on the cell to show the menu ? I need to swap to TapGesture ?

Comment: the above way there is 2 options to be able to access the clicked indexoath see edit...................

Comment: I can't access the property `cell.defectImageView.indexPath` for some reasons.

Comment: set the class name for the imageView in Ib and change the oultet to `@IBOutlet weak var defectImageView:CustomImg!`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5820010/sh-khan I edit my post with your suggestion. Can you take a look to that GIF? Maybe you have any clue why I have that bug. Thanks !

Comment: I edit the post and I added a capture with my actual issue (the indexPath is going crazy). http://g.recordit.co/VMeGZbf7TF.gif

Comment: why don't you reload the table in `receiveListImagesUpdated` ?

Comment: I reload the table in ViewWillAppear. I added now the reload also in that function but I encounter the same issue.

Comment: I fix it ! I added a new var:
`var currentIndexPath: IndexPath!`.
After I set this var in `func tapOnDefectImageView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){.... currentIndexPath = indexPath }`.
Then in `func receiveListImagesUpdated(imagesFromList: [String]?) { let item = itemSections[currentIndexPath.section].checklistItems[currentIndexPath.row] }`